# How to compare values from an array in shell script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Why don't these lines work? And is it possible to make them work? And can you explain to me how shell is reading values from an array is it as text or as integers if that's a dumb question please don't laugh I just started leaning :).

```
if  [ ${a[1]} -gt ${a[2]} ] ;
for (( b=0; b > ${a[2]}; b++));
```

```
#!/bin/bash
read a arr


if [ ${a[0]} -ne 1 ] && [ ${a[0]} -ne 2 ] && [ ${a[0]} -ne 3 ];
 then
 echo "Ne poznam vrednosti prvega parametra"
 echo "Konec skripte"
 else  
  if [ ${a[0]} -eq 1 ];
   then
   echo "Prvi parameter ima vrednost ${a[0]}"
   if  [ ${a[1]} -gt ${a[2]} ] ; 
     then
      echo "Drugi parameter je vecji ali enak tretjemu parametru."
     else
      echo "Drugi parameter ni vecji ali enak tretjemu parametru."
    fi  
  fi
  if [ ${a[0]} -eq 2 ];
    then
      echo "Prvi parametar ima vrednost: 2"
      for (( b=0; b > ${a[2]}; b++));
      do 
       
       echo "WORKS"
       
      done              
  fi    
fi
```

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/suggestions.

Comment: what do you think `read a arr` is supposed to do, especially in light of all the references to an array named `a[]`?

Comment: it lets me type values in the terminal for ex: 1 5 4

Comment: sure, but where are those values being stored?  I'm **assuming** what you want is `read -a arr` ... to store those values (`1 5 4`) in an array named `arr[]`, but then you need to fix the rest of the code so that instead of referencing an array named `a[]` you really want to reference an array named `arr[]`; alternatively, use `read -a a` to read the values into an array named `a[]`, and no need to change the follow-on references to an array named `a[]`

Comment: fwiw, `read a arr` is going to lead to `a=1` and `arr='5 4'`, with neither of the variables (`a`, `arr`) being an array

Comment: but when i change it to `read a a` it doesnt read it as an array anymore

Comment: `read -a a` (what I recommended) is not the same as `read a a` (what you've tried); and the original code (`read a arr`) was **not** storing  anything in an **array**; replace `read a arr` with `unset a` + `<newline>` + `read -a a`; the `unset a` may be overkill but ensures the `read -a a` will create a new array named `a[]`

Comment: Thank you man im so dumb. Can u now see why my for loop is not working it jst skips over it.

Comment: if your input (to the `read`) is `1 5 4` then your array looks like: `a[0]="1" a[1]="5" a[2]="4"`, this in turn means `if [ ${a[0]} -eq 2 ]` is false (ie, `if [ 1 -eq 2 ]` is false) and so your code never gets to the `for` loop, but even if your code hits the `for` loop it won't fire because you start with `b=0` but then say to run **while** `b > a[2]`, but `a[2]==4` so on the first run through the `for` loop you're saying to run **while** `0 > 4`, which is false, so the `for` loop never runs

Comment: on a line before the first `if` add `set -xv` to enable (after the last `fi` add `set +xv` to disable) debug mode, then run your script and review the debug output to see what values are being processed by each test/command

Comment: Well how do i make it work? If i input `2 3 4` i need it to print "works" 4 times. i need it to print until b reaches 4(a[2])

Comment: I've already pointed out that `b > $a[2]` says to run the `for` loop **while** `b` is greater than `$a[2]`, but if you start with `b=0`, and `${a[2]}=4`, then  you're telling the `for` loop to run **while** `0 > 4` which is never true; sooooo, perhaps change your test to ... idk ... maybe ... `b <= ${a[2]}` (so for the 1st pass `0 <= 4` is true, 2nd pass `1 <= 4` is true, 3rd pass `3 <= 4` is true, 4th pass `4 <= 4` is true, 5th pass `5 <= 4` is false) ... ???

Comment: Thank you man you have solved it for me, i can finally finish my project i wish i was not poor so i could pay you! You have not only helped me but explained it to me and im very grateful !

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is the missing space after `[` and before `]`.

And in the fire loop the 2nd expression should is loop-test or condition, which is false so the loop will not be executed. Maybe it should be `b <= ${a[2]}`

See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/ for some examples.